# Search the rows using value of dataframe

Tags: r

How to do this in R?

df1

```
Item  SubItem  Value    Count
 1      1A         A        3
 1      1B         B        2
```

df2

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

Here df1 count should search the next rows from df2. Like for Item 1, count is 3 then it should for A and next 2 rows in df2. Similarly for Item 2

Output

```
Item     SubItem  Value
  1       1A        A
  1       1A        B
  1       1A        C
  1       1B        B
  1       1B        C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to find the index of the 'Value' column in second dataset, get the sequence of 'Value' based on 'Count' and `stack` the `list` output into a two column `data.frame`

```
out <- stack(setNames(Map(function(x, y) df2$Value[match(x, df2$Value) + 
     seq(y) -1], df1$Value, df1$Count), df1$Item))[2:1]
out
#  ind values
#1   1      A
#2   1      B
#3   1      C
#4   2      B
#5   2      C

out$SubItem <- rep(df1$SubItem,  df1$Count)
out
#  ind values SubItem
#1   1      A      1A
#2   1      B      1A
#3   1      C      1A
#4   1      B      1B
#5   1      C      1B
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Item = c(1L, 1L), SubItem = c("1A", "1B"), Value = c("A", 
"B"), Count = 3:2), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L
))

df2 <- structure(list(Value = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")), 
     class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: I have edited my input included subitem also. So how do I filter based on Item and Subitem

Comment: I tried using it but getting an error. Can you please help me how to use it with this code you have suggested

Comment: @AnshulS  In the data i createdd, there is no column 'SubItem'.  But, it iss based on your updated data

Comment: @AnshulS  Can you check with the data I am using.  Updated the data.  it is not giving an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196840/discussion-between-anshul-s-and-akrun).